# r plotly drawing boxplot under density plot

Tags: r, boxplot, plotly, density-plot

Just wondering if it is possible to draw plots in plotly where the boxplot lays out horizontally under the density plot sort of like this plot below. Just curious.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164435/merge-and-perfectly-align-histogram-and-boxplot-using-ggplot2