# Merge and Perfectly Align Histogram and Boxplot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, boxplot, cowplot

since yesterday I am reading answers and websites in order to combine and align in one plot an `histogram` and a `boxplot` generated using `ggplot2` package.

This question differs from others because the `boxplot chart` needs to be reduced in `height` and `aligned` to the left outer margin of the `histogram`.

Considering the following dataset:

```
my_df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 
44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 
60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 
76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 
92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100), value= c(18, 9, 3, 
4, 3, 13, 12, 5, 8, 37, 64, 107, 11, 11, 8, 18, 5, 13, 13, 14, 
11, 11, 9, 14, 11, 14, 12, 10, 11, 10, 5, 3, 8, 11, 12, 11, 7, 
6, 6, 4, 11, 8, 14, 13, 14, 15, 10, 2, 4, 4, 8, 15, 21, 9, 5, 
7, 11, 6, 11, 2, 6, 16, 5, 11, 21, 33, 12, 10, 13, 33, 35, 7, 
7, 9, 2, 21, 32, 19, 9, 8, 3, 26, 37, 5, 6, 10, 18, 5, 70, 48, 
30, 10, 15, 18, 7, 4, 19, 10, 4, 32)), row.names = c(NA, 100L
), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", "value"))
```

I generated the boxplot:

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
my_df %>% select(value) %>%
        ggplot(aes(x="", y = value)) +
        geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue", color = "black") + 
        coord_flip() +
        theme_classic() +
        xlab("") +
        theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
              axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

and I generated the histogram

```
my_df %>% select(id, value) %>%
        ggplot() +
        geom_histogram(aes(x = value, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                       position = "identity", binwidth = 1, 
                       fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
        ylab("Relative Frequency") +
        theme_classic()
```

The result I am looking to obtain is a single plot like:
[image]

Note that the boxplot must be **reduced in height** and the **ticks must be exactly aligned** in order to give a different perspective of the same visual.

Comment: Take a look at cowplot's `plot_grid` (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/vignettes/plot_grid.html) using arguments `align='v'` and `rel_height`.

Comment: @MrGumble apparently, it is only for create a grid of different plots and not for my specific purpose. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://r-statistics.co/Top50-Ggplot2-Visualizations-MasterList-R-Code.html) under the point `Marginal Histogram / Boxplot`. `ggMarginal()` should be able to do this.

Comment: @Lap I already tried that approach but you cannot merge two plot you created. The packed creates the marginal plot by itself which I do not want. Do you think I should update the question with the code and the result of all the approaches I tried but did not work?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use either `egg`, `cowplot` or `patchwork` packages to combine those two plots. See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51220506/786542) for more complex examples.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

plt1 <- my_df %>% select(value) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x="", y = value)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = "lightblue", color = "black") + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme_classic() +
  xlab("") +
  theme(axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())

plt2 <- my_df %>% select(id, value) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = value, y = (..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                 position = "identity", binwidth = 1, 
                 fill = "lightblue", color = "black") +
  ylab("Relative Frequency") +
  theme_classic()
```

**[`egg`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/index.html)**

```
# install.packages("egg", dependencies = TRUE)
egg::ggarrange(plt2, plt1, heights = 2:1)
```

**[`cowplot`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/)**

```
# install.packages("cowplot", dependencies = TRUE)
cowplot::plot_grid(plt2, plt1, 
                   ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(2, 1),
                   align = 'v', axis = 'lr')
```

**[`patchwork`](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork)**

```
# install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
plt2 + plt1 + plot_layout(nrow = 2, heights = c(2, 1))
```

[image]