# Legends throw off alignment of multiple plots in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to align multiple plots in R, using ggplot2, so that the *x* axes line up vertically. However, as you can see, since the legends are different sizes, each 'x' axis is coming out a different width:

[image]

The code that I'm using right now is shown below. I'm happy to use any technique that works, not necessarily the approach that I'm using now.

```
th = theme(legend.key.width = unit(5, "cm"))

plots <- function() {
  ss <<- read_csv("support.csv")
  ww <<- read_csv("weight.csv")
  tt <<- read_csv("totals.csv")
  p1 <<- ggplot(data=ss, mapping=aes(t, support, colour=id)) + geom_line() + th
  p2 <<- ggplot(data=ww, mapping=aes(t, weight, colour=suppid)) + geom_line() + th
  p3 <<- ggplot(data=tt, mapping=aes(t, y, colour=total)) + geom_line() + th
  multiplot(p1, p2, p3, cols=1)
}
```

where `multiplot` is copied from [cookbook-r.com](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_(ggplot2)/). As you can see, my attempt to set the width of the legends did not work. I do need to see the legends so that I can tell which line is which (or at least make educated guesses about the middle graph).

Comment: Have you looked at the `cowplot` package?  (strange name, I know... but it can handle alignments which take into account margins and legends.

Comment: @MelissaKey I tried to install `cowplot` but it requires a later version of R than I can install on my computer (a MacBook Air from 2009).

Comment: Try either `cowplot`, `egg` or `patchwork` packages. See this answer for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164920/786542

Comment: @Tung I just successfully installed `egg`, and `egg:ggarrange` aligned everything correctly! Now seeing about how to shrink the legends, since they're taking up most of the window. But even this is workable! Thanks!

Comment: @Gregor Please don't close this question. One difference from the other question is that in my problem, the legends are causing the plots to be misaligned. I had previously looked at the other question and didn't think it was applicable because the plots there don't have legends.

Comment: @Gregor Even after applying the solution in the other question, the legends are still obscuring each other.

Comment: @BenKovitz: to tweak the legend, you can try the `lemon` package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lemon/vignettes/legends.html