# Draw two plots in R with ggplot and par

Tags: r, ggplot2

I start to study R. I'm starting with Iris dataset in the package `datasets`. To draw som graph I need to use the `ggplot2` package. How can I split the Plots window and draw two graphs?

I try with the following code, but only one graph is showed.

```
iris=datasets::iris
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species))+ geom_point(size=3)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+ geom_point(size=3)
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Comment: You are right, sorry

Comment: @xcesco: see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164920/786542

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use win.graph() to split the window into two.

Since you have not provided dataset, if you want to create a side by side plot try based on my example below

Try this:

```
library(cowplot)

iris1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot() + theme_bw()

iris2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, fill = Species)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.7) + theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8, 0.8))

plot_grid(iris1, iris2, labels = "AUTO")
```

Answer (score 3):

As `ggplot2` is based on `grid` graphics system instead of base plot, `par` does not effective in adjusting `ggplot2` plots, and the latest version of ggplot2 has already supported the arrangement of different plots, and you can set tags for each of them:

```
iris=datasets::iris
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,color=Species))+ geom_point(size=3) + labs(tag = "A") -> p1
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length,y=Petal.Width,color=Species))+ geom_point(size=3) + labs(tag = "B") -> p2
p1 + p2
```

For more sophisticated arrangement, you can use `patchwork` package to arrange them

Comment: I try your code but I received the following error: Error: Don't know how to add p2 to a plot

Comment: Please update ggplot2 to the latest version (>3.0.0), and install `patchwork` package

Comment: I did not find 'patchwork' from package repository (CRAN).

Comment: `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")` it's in Github, not CRAN