# How to adjust plot areas in ggplot?

Tags: ggplot2

I am trying to use `grid.arrange` to display multiple graphs on the same page generated by ggplot.Each subplot with difference x and y scale. Two subplot share the legend. My perpose is that to display the plot areas same size. Are there parameter to adjust plot area ( except legend area)? The `facet` is inadequate to arrange it.

```
df <- data.frame(class=paste0('a',1:20),
         x1=runif(20),
         x2=runif(20),
         y1=runif(20),
         y2=runif(20))

p1 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x1,y=y1))+
  geom_point(aes(color=class),size=2,show.legend=TRUE)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm',color='black')+
  theme_bw()

p2 <- ggplot(df,aes(x=x2,y=y2))+
  geom_point(aes(color=class),size=2,show.legend=FALSE)+
  stat_smooth(method='lm',color='black')+
  theme_bw()
grid.arrange(p1,p2,nrow=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164920/786542?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [patchwork](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork) package

```r
# install.packages("devtools", dependencies = TRUE)
# devtools::install_github("thomasp85/patchwork")
library(patchwork)
p1 / p2 +   plot_annotation(title = "Plot title",
                            subtitle = "Plot subtitle",
                            tag_levels = 'A',
                            tag_suffix = ')')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>