# Two plots same x axis, two y axis - how to arrange plots in a grid

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a graph like [this one](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/#charts), using `ggplot2` and `gridExtra` packages, but my two plots are not properly aligned one under the other. My dataset is the historical data for bitcoin from coinmarketcap.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(gridExtra)

bitc$Date <- as.Date(bitc$Date,"%m/%d/%Y")
bitc$Close <- bitc$Close/1000
bitc$Market_Cap <- bitc$Market_Cap/1000000000
bitc$Volume <- bitc$Volume/1000000000


q <- ggplot(bitc,aes(bitc$Date))+
  geom_line(aes(y=bitc$Close,colour="Close"))+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,-30,6),units="points"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(vjust =0.25)) +
  scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("6 months"))+
  xlab("Timp")+
  ylab("Price (thous. USD)")

q <- q + geom_line(aes(y=bitc$Market_Cap/10,colour="Market_Cap"))
q <- q + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10, name = "Market Cap (bld. USD)"))
q

p <- ggplot(bitc, aes(bitc$Date))+
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,5,1,1),units="points")) +
  geom_line(aes(y=bitc$Volume, colour="Volum"))+
  scale_x_date(breaks=date_breaks("6 months"))+
  scale_color_manual(values="green")+
  xlab("Time")+
  ylab("Volume (bld. USD)")

p
grid.arrange(q,p,heights = c(4/5,1/5))
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wohxa.jpg

The output of `dput(head(bitc,20))`:

```
bitc <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(15823, 15824, 15825, 15826, 
15827, 15828, 15829, 15830, 15831, 15832, 15833, 15834, 15835, 
15836, 15837, 15838, 15839, 15840, 15841, 15842), class = "Date"), 
    Open = c(135.3, 134.44, 144, 139, 116.38, 106.25, 98.1, 112.9, 
    115.98, 112.25, 109.6, 113.2, 112.8, 117.7, 115.64, 114.82, 
    117.98, 111.4, 114.22, 118.21), High = c(135.98, 147.49, 
    146.93, 139.89, 125.6, 108.13, 115, 118.8, 124.66, 113.44, 
    115.78, 113.46, 122, 118.68, 117.45, 118.7, 119.8, 115.81, 
    118.76, 125.3), Low = c(132.1, 134, 134.05, 107.72, 92.28, 
    79.1, 92.5, 107.14, 106.64, 97.7, 109.6, 109.26, 111.55, 
    113.01, 113.43, 114.5, 110.25, 103.5, 112.2, 116.57), Close = c(0.13421, 
    0.14454, 0.139, 0.11699, 0.10521, 0.09775, 0.1125, 0.11591, 
    0.1123, 0.1115, 0.11357, 0.11267, 0.1172, 0.11524, 0.115, 
    0.11798, 0.1115, 0.11422, 0.11876, 0.12301), Volume = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    Market_Cap = c(1.488566728, 1.603768865, 1.542813125, 1.298954594, 
    1.168517495, 1.085995169, 1.250316563, 1.288693176, 1.24902306, 
    1.2405936, 1.264049202, 1.254535382, 1.30547908, 1.284207489, 
    1.281982625, 1.315710011, 1.243874488, 1.274623813, 1.325726787, 
    1.373723882)), .Names = c("Date", "Open", "High", "Low", 
"Close", "Volume", "Market_Cap"), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi @Andrei Popescu could you add sample data to your question using `dput(head(mydata,20))`?

Comment: i just want my graphs to have the same length, exactly like the one on the website

Comment: Maybe make your data a timeseries and use `library(xts)`?

Comment: i made it a time series and after that how do i put the x variable in aes because the date it's not a column anymore? thank you!

Comment: Sorry I can't take a look at the question just now. `ggplot` has an `autoplot` function that I've used before using the `forecast` package. Maybe someone else will help you give a detailed answer.

Comment: @AndreiPopescu: try these packages https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164920/786542

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did a great job already. I suggest you to try out the `cowplot` package, specifically the function `plot_grid` to nicely arrange multiple plots into a grid. You can find vignettes for the package [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cowplot/index.html).

```
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(q,p, align = "hv", ncol = 1, rel_heights = c(4/5, 1/5))
```

With the data and the code that you provided, the above `plot_grid` gives this:

[image]

By the way, if you want interactive plots, try out the `plotly` package. It takes a "ggplot" and attempts to make it interactive - try this out:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(q)
```

More about `plotly`: [on CRAN page](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotly/index.html), [its main web page](https://plot.ly/r/) or [this book](https://plotly-book.cpsievert.me/). Could be nice to impress your colleagues and professors at ASE ;) Keep up the nice work & "Sarbatori Fericite!".

Comment: Thank you! that's much better