# Is there a way to plot multiple plot types (i.e., bar chart and adjacent strip chart) on the same plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I'd like to display a bar plot with an adjacent series of strip charts, both with different y-axes, on the same overall plot. Can someone please suggest a way to to do this if possible?

The goal is to use a bar plot to show fold-change for qPCR, and then in the same figure show the individual dCt values for control and treatment groups that were used to generate the fold-change. The bar plot and strip chart need different y-axes.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure about the dual plot types, but you can find information on dual axis at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right and that might help for one part of your issue hopefully

Comment: Have you looked into `cowplot` or `gridExtra`? They're great packages for plotting multiple plots together (after making each plot individually).

Comment: Thank you both for the very fast replies - I really appreciate your help.  Best wishes to you.

Comment: @Jeff: take a look at this too https://stackoverflow.com/a/48164920/786542