# Perfectly align horizontal boxplot under histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram, boxplot

I am asking this question which sounds exactly like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164435/merge-and-perfectly-align-histogram-and-boxplot-using-ggplot2) because it did not solve the problem. Here is my question. I have 2 plots that I want to put together with their scale perfectly in line. Here is what I got to :
[image]

As you can see the x axis is not exactly in line. Here is the code I used

```
bp_horiz<-ggplot(df,aes(y=Corg_rate))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="Corg annual rate")+
  coord_flip()

histo<-ggplot(data=df, aes(Corg_rate))+
  geom_histogram(fill="grey",col="black")+
  labs(x="Corg annual rate",y="Counts")+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(x=NULL,y="Counts")

plot_grid(histo,boxplot_horiz,ncol=1,align="v",rel_heights=c(4,1),axis = 'lr')
```

I tried to change the align parameters from v to h to hv without success. 
I tried using egg with the same problem on non alignment. I tried using ggMarginal but it does not work when the center plot is a histogram.

How would you solve this issue?

I do't know how to add data but to make things clearer here is the beginning of it:

```
   Corg_rate
 1  -0.0147 
 2   0.0106 
 3   0.114  
 4  -0.00230
 5   0.0105 
 6  -0.0574
 7   0.0102 
 8  -0.00472
 9   0.0335 
10  -0.00803
```

Comment: Where does `plot_grid` come from, `cowplot`?

Comment: @camille yes it is the cowplot package

Comment: How exactly does that other post not solve the problem? The answer there has 3 different methods—none work? Without your data, we can't test this to see what does or doesn't work

Comment: yes none works. I will update the question to add my data

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way: writing the scale for each plot. I have therefore added to the code

- for the boxplot (before coord_flip)

```
+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(df$Corg_rate),max(df$Corg_rate)))
```

- and for the histogram

```
+scale_x_continuous(limits=c(min(df$Corg_rate),max(df$Corg_rate)))
```

The function plot_grid then works just fine and the two plots have their scales aligned