# How can I align my ggplots when grid.arrange()?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two ggplots (boxplots) I want to be aligned in one graph, but I'm facing a problem :
[see the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57HHZ.png). Indeed, my **two x-axis aren't aligned** and I don't know how to change it.
I'm just doing a grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2, nrow = 1)

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48164435/merge-and-perfectly-align-histogram-and-boxplot-using-ggplot2/48164920#48164920

Comment: This would be easier to answer if you included the code used to create the boxplots

Comment: @ConorNeilson yes of course, sorry, here it is :

`bp_al <- ggplot(al, aes(x = Subst, y = Concentration)) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill = "blue", width = 0.5) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, size = 8),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "blue", size = 7)) +
  theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0,-0.3,0,-0.5), "cm")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 30000, 9500)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.8, 0))`

and same for the other one

Comment: @Tung thank you! i've tried this but i think that the problem comes from my graphs, the x axis is higher in one graph, automatically... i don't know how to fix it

Comment: You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to quickly create a reproducible example so others can help. Please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)